# How to tell Users that a Tooltip lies behind a Text/Textbox/Image, etc.?

Tags: interface, windows-os, users, tooltips, experience

In my UI, I have a normal text headline that covers a block of checkboxes. Without further information I'm scared of users not knowing what to do with the window. My idea is to put a tooltip in the headline to give users information about the function of my window.

How do I make clear that there actually is a tooltip behind that headline? I don't think people would normally hover over the headline so they would never get the information. Is there some sort of specific system to imply that there will be a tooltip over a control or text (like some special cursor)?

Comment: Can you provide examples of this UI you are describing? Further to that, why are you covering the block of checkboxes behind something if you want the user to see them?

Comment: it will help to see an image of the case to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a fan of using a dashed underline to indicate a tooltip.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

*A tool-tip is not the UI you are looking for*

As you correctly state tooltip is suitable for information on a specific item. Not the intent of the whole UI.  What you want to do is present an option for "in-line help" on the UI here are [ideas on how to do this include interactive callout, embedded text or icon](http://baymard.com/blog/inline-help)

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGPwtM.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>